# SSD testing equivalent of Memtest for RAM?

Tags: ssd, memtest, hard-drive-failure

How does one check if their SSD is failing? I randomly started getting BSOD's for memory and storage related issues... memtest checked out fine, how can I test to see if the SSD might be the culprit?

Edit: it's a ocz vertex 3

Answer (score 2):

What make is the drive?  Check the vendor site for tools.

Many vendors offer a "toolbox" to maintain the drive.  [Intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18455) has one here

Saw this tool as well [SSD Life](http://ssd-life.com/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a know issue with the Vertex 3 drive (and other SandForce 2 based SSDs). It is not that the drive is failing, but that it is buggy. When the drive idles it goes into some sort of sleep state, from which it wakes up when it needs to do something. Occasionally it fails this transition and drops out. Windows doesn't like having the drive disappear so it BSODs. There isn't anything you can do about this other than keep installing firmware updates as they come out and hope the get these issues fixed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The testing capability is built in. Install smartmontools. The incantations you need are:

1. smartctl -a
   Shows you the SMART status including any current test status.
2. smartctl --test=short
   Initiates a short self-test
3. smartctl --test=long
   Initiates a long self-test.

If tests pass and no SMART attributes are showing failure, the disk is OK.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check sector integrity there's always `chkdsk`.

Run:
`chkdsk /r`

Source: https://forum.corsair.com/v2/showthread.php?p=536887